# Bootstrap popover flickering

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap popover inside a div that has a tooltip. When you position the cursor over the popover in certain areas, it flickers.

I tried fixing the flicker by turning off tip when popover was fired but that did not work.

```
$('.item').tooltip();
$('.status-pop').mouseover(function() {
  $('.item').tooltip('hide')
});
```

I cannot figure out what is causing this. Any help appreciated.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/infatti/h3pUM/

Comment: You should spend some time with [validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org/) as you have invalid markup which may be causing some of your problem. Look specifically at what elements are invalid inside of other elements (`h6` within an `a` for example).

Comment: It appears that the popover is not well-placed (old bug due to jQuery 1.8, if I remember right). Could you strip down the problem to standard Twitter Bootstrap css (using the Resources on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3pUM/1/)) ? [TWBS CDN](http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on this link: http://vkubushyn.wordpress.com/2012/04/05/multiple-tooltipspopovers-on-the-same-element-in-twitter-bootstrap/. It allows you to have multiple tooltips, popovers etc.

Comment: looks promising, I will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some crude testing on this and it seems to only happen when the popover is set to anything other than right.
if you change your Fiddle to put the popover on the right then it works fine.
There may be a bug in bootstrap popover/twipsy javascript.